# What's a browser Target in chrome DevTools protocol?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, puppeteer

In the main website of chrome DevTools protocol, there's a [section](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/) for **Target Domain**.

In puppeteer library, there's a JS class for that, And it has got just a few methods.

What's Target and What's for?

Comment: It's any frame (the main page is also a frame, extension pages too).

Comment: Thanks, So you mean it refers to new Tab itself, in general?

Comment: Tabs can contain multiple targets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A **target**, as described in your question, can be a page, background page, service worker, browser, and more.

In other words, a target is essentially the current frame or environment that is in focus.

---

The [Chrome DevTools Protocol Documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/) describes the Target Domain as:

> #### Target Domain
>
> Supports additional targets discovery and allows to attach to them.

---

[Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), a Node.js library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol, has a Target class which is [documented](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-target) as the following:

> #### class: Target
>
> **target.browser()**
>
> - returns: <[Browser](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-browser)>
>
> Get the browser the target belongs to.
>
> **target.browserContext()**
>
> - returns: <[BrowserContext](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-browsercontext)>
>
> The browser context the target belongs to.
>
> **target.createCDPSession()**
>
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<[CDPSession](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession)>>
>
> Creates a Chrome Devtools Protocol session attached to the target.
>
> **target.opener()**
>
> - returns: <?[Target](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-target)>
>
> Get the target that opened this target. Top-level targets return `null`.
>
> **target.page()**
>
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<?[Page](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-page)>>
>
> If the target is not of type `"page"` or `"background_page"`, returns `null`.
>
> **target.type()**
>
> - returns: <[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)>
>
> Identifies what kind of target this is. Can be `"page"`, `"background_page"`, `"service_worker"`, `"browser"` or `"other"`.
>
> **target.url()**
>
> - returns: <[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)>